# hide specific div on single.php

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, loop, single

I've been working on WP since  a week so far i've seen bunch of tutorials and videos about wp but i feel stuck and since i'm a wp noob i cant find or think any solution for a simple problem.
i have created custom field using plug-in for a custom post type, my problem is i want to hide the -div- when there is nothing written in the field.

So far i tried bunch of entries from this site and SO but i havent complished anything. all i need is a basic structure for hiding the -div- in case if there is no entry for the related post field..

below my single.php's -div- part that i want to hide... since im new and watched so much stuff i feel extremely confused and cant develop any solution..

```
<div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne1">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" href="#collapseOne1" aria-expanded="true"
                    aria-controls="collapseOne1">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                      <?php the_field('button1-mi-s1-b'); ?> <i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
                    </h5>
                  </a>
                </div>

                <!-- Card body -->
                <div id="collapseOne1" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne1"
                  data-parent="#accordionEx">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <?php the_field('button1-mi-s1-yazi'); ?>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
```

thanks for your time..
best regards
WP_NOOB

Answer (score 1):

So i resolved that noob question... here is a recipe step by step;

1. get some sleep
2. repeat what you leaned with a fresh mind
3. apply the structure:

```
<?php if( get_field('field_name') ): ?>
    <p>My field value: <?php the_field('field_name'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try following to show a specific piece of code if there is something in it.

```
if( get_field('field_name') != '' )
  {
    // All Conditional HTML must be kept here.
    the_field('field_name');
  }
```

As the Variable **get_field('field_name')** will always be there , you just need of check if it holds a blank or Some Real piece of Value.
This is the reason behind that !empty doesn't work here.

Comment: The  `! empty( $var )`  condition ([see php `empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)) is helpful here - checks for a number of empty conditions including empty arrays, whitespace, NULL, false etc. and means you can use strict comparison operators - See [WPCS](https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/php/) _"Unless absolutely necessary, loose comparisons should not be used, as their behaviour can be misleading."_